# How do I enable multiple user accounts on my ZTE Axon 7?

Tags: zte

According to [GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/zte_axon_7_ota_rolling_out_with_multiuser_support_and_quick_settings_tile_support-news-27062.php) the ZTE Axon 7 should be able to support multiple user accounts.
I have currently MiFavor UI 4.2 installed and that shows as the most up to date.

I don't see the icon in the top corner. How do I get it to work?

Comment: Go into your phone settings, and see if you have a setting called users. If it doesn't, it would then mean that your phone probably doesn't have it